# Use Pydantic with strict=False to coerce UUIDs in a structure to strings?

Tags: python, pydantic

In a Python 3.12 codebase using Pydantic 2.5.3, I'm trying to coerce a dictionary into a form where it contains only JSON-serializeable values (without actually converting it all the way to JSON at this time).

```py
import uuid, pydantic
```

I have a type definition akin to the following:

```py
type JsonDict = dict[str, "JsonTypes"]
type JsonTypes = None | str | float | bool | int | list["JsonTypes"] | JsonDict
```

I also have a value that *would* be JSON-serializable, but for presence of a UUID:

```
myValue = {
  "keyA": {
    uuid.UUID('0589f92c-37b1-4837-983a-3fdc2d8416ea'): {
      "keyB": uuid.UUID('a98251e6-2d80-407f-9975-4918f0a28119'),
    },
  },
}
```

---

In general, pydantic's `strict=False` mode is willing to coerce things to the desired type when the type definition calls for it; but for some reason, that isn't true here:

```py
adapter = pydantic.TypeAdapter(JsonDict)
adapter.validate_python(myValue, strict=False)
```

...fails with:

```
keyA.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value={UUID('0589f92c-37b1-4837...7f-9975-4918f0a28119')}}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/string_type
keyA.`dict[str,nullable[union[str,float,bool,int,list[...],...]]]`.UUID('0589f92c-37b1-4837-983a-3fdc2d8416ea').[key]
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=UUID('0589f92c-37b1-4837-983a-3fdc2d8416ea'), input_type=UUID]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/string_type
```

(and many further errors, describing why none of the other possibilities apply).

---

By contrast, if using a dataclass or a proper `pydantic.BaseModel` derivative, one *can* coerce all the way to JSON even with the UUIDs present:

```
@pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass
class MyValueType:
  keyA: dict[uuid.UUID, dict[str, uuid.UUID]]

myValueObj = MyValueType(**myValue)
myValueJson = pydantic.RootModel[MyValueType](myValueObj).model_dump_json()
```

...but I don't know how to stop at "JSON-serializable" without actually going all the way to JSON: Changing `.model_dump_json()` to `.model_dump()` in the last snippet leaves the UUID objects *as UUIDs* without serializing them to strings.

Comment: The trick was to use `model_dump(mode='json')`, as given in an answer to the linked duplicate.